# remove load() from div and return to original div contents?

Tags: jquery, html, load

I've got most of what I want working, but this last bit requires I throw myself on the stackoverflow gods, because I'm stumped. I have a long list of sub-menu options. When a user clicks on one, it replaces another div's contents with new contents, and also marks the sub-menu li with class="active". This part works great, but the problem is undoing it. Here's the basic html:

```
<div id="coleft">
<ul id="charactermenu">
    <li id="base_chara" class="active">basic info</li>
    <li id="base_names" class="">names</li>
    <li id="base_speech" class="">speech</li>
    <li id="base_psyche" class="">psyche</li>
    <li id="base_personality" class="">personality</li>
    <li id="base_habits" class=" ">habits</li>
</ul>
<div id="coright">
    /... some content goes here
</div>
```

And here's the simple script that takes the #id and flips the div contents:

```
$('#charactermenu li').click(function() {
    var selection = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#coright").html(ajax_load).load( selection + ".php").fadeIn();
    $("#" + selection).addClass('active');
    $("#" + selection).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

When the page first opens, it shows as default the contents of #coright, which is #base_chara. But if I click onto something else and then back onto the first sub-menu option (#base_chara), it wants to load that div just like the rest. I've ended up duplication the #base_chara contents into a separate base_chara.php, so right now I have two files to track for that sub-menu option, ugh. It seems like there's got to be a way to something like this:

```
#base_chara click(function)
    remove loaded php from div
    display original div contents
    removeClass for everyone else
    add active for #base_chara
```

But when a div is replaced in this manner, does the original content get wiped? What's the easiest/best way to manage this? Unload() seems to be related to the entire window (not just a div), and remove() and empty() leave me with nothing in #coright at all. Where am I going wrong?

ETA: I just realized I could get around this one by using require_once('dbconnect.php') instead of simple include. Which is to say, the problem is resolved but the question remains unanswered, and I'd still like to know if there is a simple way to handle this on a jquery/javascript level. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, for each menu item, you want to save the contents so that when the user clicks a menu item, if those contents are saved, just show them rather than load them?

Comment: Loading/reloading for the other links is all the same. I just wanted to know whether you can have info in a div, populate that div with something else, then un-populate the div and show the original (from page loading) div contents. Does that make more sense? (Sorry, I guess I get wordy when I've banged my head against the wall too many times!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're askind to keep the contents if they have been loaded rather than reload them. 
So keep all the contents in divs and hide the ones you don't want to show.

Not checked for errors.

```
$('#charactermenu li').click(function() {
    var selection = $(this).attr('id');

    var el=$('#coright div[data-selection="' + selection + '"]');

    // does this item not have a pane?
    if (!el.length) {
        el=$('<div/>', {class:'pane'}).data('selection', selection)
            .appendTo('#coright')
            .html(ajax_load).load( selection + ".php");
    }
    el.fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});


<div id="coright">
    <div class="pane" data-selection="base_chara">
        /... some content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean! At least, on a pseudocode level. On the actual code, I'm struggling (learning jquery as I go). So you set up a var for the selection, then a var for the data-selection (?) but why to get the yes/no on pane do you get the length of el? Is that just a different way to say "if el exists"?

Comment: If you like you can write a function to return a boolean $.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;} and use if ($(el).exists()){...}. Length is the correct way and 0=false and >0=true so why write more?

Comment: RE setting up a var for the data-selection - would you rather make jQuery search to DOM every time you want to find/change it, and have to write it out every time, or just do things faster and easier to maintain?

Comment: ohhhh, so the complexity is because I'm adding to the SAME div, instead of just hiding the first div and showing a second div! So I can solve the whole thing just by having two divs -- the original (that gets hidden when something else is clicked) and a second that gets populated when clicked, and hidden if unclicked? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes. More than two divs actually - as many as there are menu items.

Comment: Didn't realize that about length being the better/correct way to check if exists. I'd just been doing more like if (el) and if (!el).

Comment: if (el) will return true whether there are matched elements or not because you're creating that object with var el=$(...).

Answer (score 1):

Store the original contents of the div in a javascript variable before loading the new contents. Then check if the user selected the original option. Repopulate the div from the stored contents.